# Xcode 8 & Swift 3 - Scroll View and .Xib Files not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

So I followed a tutorial online to make snapchat like menu. I used this tutorial to make a entire app. Since upgrading to **Xcode 8** and ***swift  3***, I can no longer get the .Xib file to load.

I have a scroll view, with a .xib file being loaded onto that. using this code

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var V1 : View1 = View1(nibName: "View1", bundle: nil)


    self.addChildViewController(V1)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(V1.view)
    V1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

This use to work but when I build and run nothing happens, this is what the screen is meant to look like
[.Xib inside Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11GWh.png)

But this is what it runs like

[While running in the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UREIu.png)

Any help would be greatly thanked.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong.

```
var V1 = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("View1", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! View1
```

Comment: What is the [0] for? Thanks for your help i will try this!

Comment: @k.Blacker `loadNibNamed` will give you an array of top-level views in your `.xib` file. If you have only one root view, which contains everything else - then just write `[0]` to take the first element from array. Is there something else printed in console log when the crash occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I have observed this issue while migrating to xCode 8 with scroll views.

To resolve this issue add a view e.g content view inside the scroll view in the storyboard. The frame of the content view should be exactly equal to scroll view with with all edges aligning to scroll view, with fixed height and fixed width. You can change scroll view contentSize later programatically.

Add the the view from the xib file as a subview to the content view.

[image]

Comment: Cheers! Helped loads!